# Cómo saber si el cliente recibió la respuesta de servidor (WCF)

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net, webservice, wcf

Mi duda es como seria para que el cliente al recibir la respuesta de su petición confirme que la recibió correctamente esto a un servicio WCF

Cliente -->'petición'->-Servicio-->'respuesta'-->cliente--'confirmación de recibido'-->Servicio

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar

Gracias

Comment: Por favor agrega mas información. *Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Si entiendo bien, ¿quieres que el cliente confirme que la respuesta del servicio le llegó correctamente?, si es así, ¿has intentado crear otro servicio que se invoque cuando el cliente lo consuma? = así sabrías que el cliente recibió el primero servicio...

Comment: de echo el servicio ya lo tengo implementado ahora solo seria poner una opcion de confirmación.

Tengo una idea de como comentas seria usar un metodo que guarde el id de peticion y si todo sale correcto regrese ese id para saber que la respuesta fue recivida exitosamente, pero queria saber si hay algun metodo nativo dentro del wcf que puediese hacer esa funcion.

Saludos

Comment: Entonces **debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.